# Powershell : merge two CSV files with partially duplicate lines

Tags: powershell, csv

I have scraped two files from a website in order to list the companies in my city.
The first lists : name, city, phone number, email
The second lists : name, city, phone number

And I will have duplicate lines if I merge them, as an example, i will have the following :

```
> "Firm1";"Los Angeles";"000000";"info@firm1.lol"
> "Firm1";"Los Angeles";"000000";""
> "Firm2";"Los Angeles";"111111";""
> "Firm3";"Los Angeles";"000000";"contact@firm3.lol"
> "Firm3";"Los Angeles";"000000";""
> ...
```

Is there a way to merge the two files and keep the max info like this :

```
> "Firm1";"Los Angeles";"000000";"info@firm1.lol"
> "Firm2";"Los Angeles";"111111";""
> "Firm3";"Los Angeles";"000000";"contact@firm3.lol"
> ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the fact you've got a file like this called 'firm.csv'

```
"Firm1";"Los Angeles";"000000";"info@firm1.lol"
"Firm1";"Los Angeles";"000000";""
"Firm2";"Los Angeles";"111111";""
"Firm3";"Los Angeles";"000000";"contact@firm3.lol"
"Firm3";"Los Angeles";"000000";""
```

You can load it using :

```
$firms = import-csv C:\temp\firm.csv -Header 'Firm','Town','Tel','Mail' -Delimiter ';'
```

Then

```
$firms | Sort-Object -Unique -Property 'Firm'
```

According to Joey's comment I improved the solution :

```
$firms |  Group-Object -Property 'firm' | % {$_.group | Sort-Object -Property mail -Descending | Select-Object -first 1}
```

Comment: Note that `Sort-Object` doesn't guarantee a stable sort, so you have no control over which rows will be retained in this case. Could very well be those without an e-mail address.

Comment: I use it in a lot of production script, have you got some real samples of 'unstable sort' ?

Comment: It's just that the documentation doesn't explicitly guarantee stability here, which makes me wary in assuming it will always be stable. This may work now and even indefinitely, but I've been bitten by such things in the past (not in PowerShell, though).

Comment: In this case it *is* problematic already: Generate a test file with `1..50|%{$v=$_;"""Firm$_"";""Los Angeles"";""$('info','contact','mail'|random)@firm$_.blah""";0..(random -min 3 -max 15)|%{"""Firm$v"";""Los Angeles"";"""""}} > test.csv` and then try your approach (Note that the test file leaves out the phone number column). The test file contains each firm between 4 and 16 times, the first instance of which is *always* with an e-mail address. So the expected result would be that you have each firm with an e-mail address in the end. Which is not the case.

Comment: Your approach probably works correct for tiny examples because `Array.Sort` in .NET uses a different algorithm for arrays shorter than 16 elements, which *is* stable. However, after that it switches to Quicksort, which is not.

Comment: Look it's just because my command line don't take care of the fact that mail may be empty. It's not completly correct but you comment can be use to find a solution.

Comment: The point is that `Sort -u` essentially returns a random row of all that compare equal. I'm not sure this is solvable with this approach.

Comment: I agree with this, still searching.

Answer (score 0):

There must be better approach but this is one costy way to do this.

```
$firms = import-csv C:\firm.csv -Header 'Firm','Town','Tel','Mail' -Delimiter ';'

$Result = @()
ForEach($i in $firms){

   $found = 0;

   ForEach($m in $Result){

    if($m.Firm -eq $i.Firm){

        $found = 1

        if( $i.Mail.length -ne 0 )
        {   
           $m.Mail = $i.Mail
        }
        break;
      }
   }

   if($found -eq 0){
        $Result += [pscustomobject] @{Firm=$i.Firm; Town=$i.Town; Tel=$i.Tel; Mail=$i.Mail}
   }
}

$Result | export-csv C:\out.csv
```

Comment: You should probably not use `-match` there, as it would match substrings as well (and things like `.` and other regex metacharacters can be problematic). `-eq` should do fine there.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: just realized the two files don't contain the same headers. Here is an update.

```
$main = Import-Csv firm1.csv -Header 'Firm','Town','Tel','Mail' -Delimiter ";"
$alt = Import-Csv firm2.csv -Header 'Firm','Town','Tel' -Delimiter ";" 

foreach ($f in $alt)
{
    $found = $false
    foreach($g in $main)
    {
        if ($g.Firm -eq $f.Firm -and $g.city -eq $f.city) 
        {
            $found = $true

            if ($g.Tel -eq "")
            {
                $g.Tel = $f.Tel
            }
        }
    }
    if ($found -eq $false)
    {
        $main += $f
    }
}


# Everything is merged into the $main array 
$main
```